# Max Repeated Word in a string

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying to do a very common interview problem "Finding the max repeated word in a string " and could not find much resources in net for c/c++ implementation. So I coded it myself here. 
I have tried to do most of the coding from scratch for better understanding.
Could you review my code and provide comments on my algorithm. Some people have suggested using hashtables for storing the count, but am not using hashtables here.

```
#include<stdafx.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string word[10];

//splitting string into words
int parsestr(string str)
{   
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int maxlength = str.length();
    int wordcnt = 0;
    while(i < maxlength)
    {
        if(str[i]!= ' ')
        {
            word[index] = word[index]+str[i];
        }
        else
        {
            index++;//new word
            wordcnt = index;
        }
    i++;
    }
    return wordcnt;
}

//find the max word count out of the array and return the word corresponding to that index.
string maxrepeatedWord(int wordcntArr[],int count)
{
int max = 0;
int index = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
    {
        if(wordcntArr[i] > max)
        {
        max = wordcntArr[i];
        index = i;
        }
    }

    return word[index];
}
void countwords(int count)
{
    int wordcnt = 0;
    int wordcntArr[10];
    string maxrepeatedword;
    for(int i=0;i<=count ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=count;j++)
        {
            if(word[i]==word[j])
            {
            wordcnt++;
            //word[j] = "";
            }
            else
            {}
        }
        cout<<" word "<< word[i] <<" occurs "<< wordcnt <<" times "<<endl;
        wordcntArr[i] = wordcnt;
        wordcnt = 0;
    }

    maxrepeatedword = maxrepeatedWord(wordcntArr,count);
    cout<< " Max Repeated Word is " << maxrepeatedword;
}

int main()
{
string str = "I am am am good good";
int wordcount = 0;
wordcount = parsestr(str);
countwords(wordcount);
}
```

Comment: This is better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Matt: sorry about that. didnt know they had a seperate page for code review. will post it there.Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Use headers like `cstdio`, not `stdio.h`, for C library headers in C++. And what's wrong with `std::vector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the sake of comparison, the most obvious way to do this is C++ is:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input("I am am am good good");
    std::map<std::string, int> count;
    std::string word;
    decltype(count)::const_iterator most_common;
    while (input >> word)
    {
        auto iterator = count.emplace(word, 0).first;
        ++iterator->second;
        if (count.size() == 1 ||
            iterator->second > most_common->second)
            most_common = iterator;
    }
    std::cout << '\"' << most_common->first << "' repeated "
         << most_common->second << " times\n";
}
```

See it run [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bac6defdfd2281d8).

Notes:

- [`map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) returns a `pair<iterator,bool>` indicating where the word & its count are in the `map`, and whether its newly inserted.  We only care about *where* so capture `emplace(...).first`.
- As we update the count, we check if that makes the word the most-common word seen so far.  If so we copy the iterator to the local variable `most_common`, so we have a record of both the most commonly seen word so far and its count.

Some things you're doing that are worth thinking about:

- `word` is a global variable - it's a good habit to pass things as function arguments unless it's terribly inconvenient, means the code can be reused more easily from async signal handlers or other threads, and it's more obvious in looking at a function call site what the inputs and outputs might be.  As is, the call `countwords(wordcount)` makes it look like countwords' only input is the `int wordcount`.
- fixed sized arrays: if you've more than 10 words, you're sunk.  C++ Standard containers can grow on demand.
- there are a few convenience functions you could use, such as `std::string::operator+=(char)` to append a `char` more concisely ala `my_string += my_char;`

Generally though, your code is quite sensible and shows a good understanding of iteration and problem solving, doing it all very low-level but that's good stuff to understand in a very hands-on way.

Answer (score 0):

### Code Snippet :

```
void mostRepeat(string words[], int n)
{
    int hash[n]={0};

    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        if(words[j]==words[i])  hash[j]++;
      }
    }

    int maxi = hash[0];
    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       if(maxi<hash[i])
       {
          maxi=hash[i];
          index = i;
       }
    }
    cout<<words[index]<<endl;
}
```

Full program : [Link](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/oH3BtN)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringWordDuplicates {

    static void duplicate(String inputString){

        HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        String[] words = inputString.split(" ");

        for(String word : words){
            if(wordCount.containsKey(word)){
                wordCount.put(word, wordCount.get(word)+1);             
            }
            else{
                wordCount.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
        //Extracting of all keys of word count
        Set<String> wordsInString = wordCount.keySet();

        for(String word : wordsInString){
            if(wordCount.get(word)>1){
                System.out.println(word+":"+wordCount.get(word));
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        duplicate("I am Java Programmer and IT Server Programmer with Java as Best Java lover");

    }
}
```